# Laravel Queue error when using database driver

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

I'm getting the following error when pushing a job to a laravel 5.2 Queue, using the database driver.

> exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'No connector for
>   []' in
>   /var/www/krsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php:150

The queue is running with supervisor and the following setup

```
[program:krsa-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/krsa/artisan queue:work —tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/krsa/supervisor/worker.log
```

.env file points to the database driver

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

config/queue.php file has correct settings:

```
'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
```

table `jobs` exists and has the correct columns.

The same settings work on another project on a different server.
I've made composer update and made sure all dependencies are installed, unless there are extra dependencies I am not aware of for the database driver.

Can't figure out why Laravel is not picking up the connector/driver. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE***
When I run `php artisan queue:work` the queue processes all jobs correctly.

Comment: Try this `QUEUE_DRIVER="database"`?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @KevinRED yes but I don't remember what is was, I think the issue was that some files under vendor/ folder were not updated correctly when I upgraded to 5.2. I had to compare against the open source version.

Answer (score -1):

I've just run into this too. It'll likely be because `tries` doesn't have two hyphens before it, only one in your case